# Real-time calculating of input values with mysql loop

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I would like to automatically calculate `<input>` values which are generated via MySQL. Here's my code:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link href="plugins/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet"> 
<script src="plugins/jquery/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="plugins/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>TEST 1</h1>
<?php
require("dbconnect.php");
$e= mysql_query("select center from center") or die(mysql_error());
$g = 1;
while($f = mysql_fetch_array($e))
{
    ?>
    <?php echo $f['center'].': '; ?> <input type="text" class="form-control" name="<?php echo $f['center']; ?>" id="<?php echo $g;?>" onkeyup="calc1()"/><br />
    <?php
    $g++;   
}
?>  
Answer: <input type="text" class="form-control" name="ans" id="ans" readonly/>
<script>
function calc1()
{
    var no = <?php echo json_encode($g); ?>;
    var i = 1;
    while(i <= no)
    {
        var vl = document.getElementById('i').value ;
        var v2 += Number(vl);
        $('#ans').val(v2);
        i++;
    }
    //alert(no);
}
</script>
<br />
<h1>TEST 2</h1>
<input type="text" name="1" id="1" onkeyup="calc()" />
<input type="text" name="2" id="2" onkeyup="calc()" />
<input type="text" name="answer" id="answer" readonly/>
<script>
function calc()
{
    var vl = document.getElementById('1').value;
    var v2 = document.getElementById('2').value;
    var v3 = (Number(vl)+Number(v2));
    $('#answer').val(v3);
    //alert(v3);
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Sample 1 generates `<input>` depending on the MySQL data, and I want those `<input>` values be added and displayed on the last textbox. Sample 2 is just a test addition of two textboxes and should display the sum of the two textboxes on the last textbox, but both are not working. What is wrong with my code? Any help or guidance will be appreciated.

**UPDATE!**

With Sean's help, I have changed the function to this:

```
function calc1()
{
    var no = <?php echo json_encode($g); ?>;
    var i = 1;
    var v2 = 0;
    while(i <= no)
    {
        var vl = document.getElementById(i).value ;
        v2 += Number(vl);
        i++;
    }
    $('#ans').val(v2);
    //alert(no);
}
```

Which still doesn't work. I was able to have the Sample 2 work though. Fault was I have set Sample 2's textboxes as `1` and `2` (my fault), which are also Sample 1's textboxes' ids. So I have now changed it to this, which made it worked now.

```
<h1>TEST 2</h1>
<input type="text" name="1" id="tb1" onkeyup="calc()" />
<input type="text" name="2" id="tb2" onkeyup="calc()" />
<input type="text" name="answer" id="answer" readonly/>
<script>
function calc()
{
    var vl = document.getElementById('tb1').value;
    var v2 = document.getElementById('tb2').value;
    var v3 = (Number(vl)+Number(v2));
    $('#answer').val(v3);
    //alert(v3);
}
</script>
```

The only problem now is how to make Sample 1 to work.

Comment: why do you include jQuery, but use `document.getElementById('i').value`?  if you have jQuery loaded you could easily do `$('#"+i).val()`. Note, just realized that you are quoting your `i` -> `'i'`, but since it is a javascript variable it needs to be unquoted `i`.

Comment: your `Sample 2` works fine here http://jsfiddle.net/qxvk5hc9/

Comment: @sean, for some reasons, it doesn't seem to work when I run it here in my browser. It always outputs zero.

Comment: my guess on your 1st code block is that you need to do `var vl = document.getElementById(i).value ;` instead of `var vl = document.getElementById('i').value ;` as `i` is a javascript variable, not a string. see my [first comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31932197/real-time-calculating-of-input-values-with-mysql-loop#comment51776067_31932197)

Comment: Changed `var v1 = document.getElementById(i).value ;` but it still doesn't work.

Comment: It looks like your `var v2 += Number(vl);` is an issue as it is overwriting `v2` on every loop, not increasing it. define it before the loop, and then increase it inside. also, you want to set your value after your loop - see http://jsfiddle.net/0L1h7kxm/

Comment: Did what you said, but to no avail. No output is displaying. Am I wrapping my javascript function correctly? Because it seems to work on jsfiddle but not locally.

Comment: Ah! I found the reason why Sample 2 isn't working on mine. I have set their ids to `1` & `2`, which are also the ids of the textboxes on the Sample 1. Guess that's my fault. Well, the only problem now is how to make Sample 1 work.